# Is it true/false that $ W=\{(0,0,a_3):a_3 \in R \} $ then $W=\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true/false that  $ W=\{(0,0,a_3):a_3 \in R \} $ then $W=\mathbb{R}$ ?

---

Pretty sure it is True.  Just throwing me off the line has to be along the first component ,second or third by tradition.

I do not think it matters but I been wrong before.

Will it matter if the line is not along an any axis. Will it be still denoted as $\mathbb{R} ?$

Comment: The title $\neq$ the post.

Comment: fixing it sorry @Workaholic

Comment: There is a bijection from $W\rightarrow R$, but that does not mean they are equal.

Comment: They are different sets, but they have lots of similarities

Comment: It is not true. What holds is that $W\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and as @Daniel posted there is a one-to-one mapping between $W$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The statement is false.

Comment: Glad I asked and got clear that on my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb R$ is the collection of real numbers. Elements of $\Bbb R$ are of the form $x$ where $x$ is a real number.

Elements of your set $W$, however, are of the form $(0,0,a_3)$ where $a_3$ is a real number. These are not elements of $\Bbb R$ so $W\neq \Bbb R$.

For example $(0,0,1)\in W$ but $(0,0,1)\notin\Bbb R$.

You've tagged your post as [linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) so you may be interested in the vector space structure of $W$. It's quite easy to prove that $W$ is a *one-dimensional subspace* of $\Bbb R^3$. This implies that $W$ is *linearly isomorphic* to $\Bbb R$.

In other words, $W\neq\Bbb R$ but $W\simeq \Bbb R$ as vector spaces.